# VBA Text Filter on Column with Dynamic Filter Values From Cell

Tags: excel, vba, filter

In Cell C5 I have the filter values coming from a listbox selection.

```
Current values are:  Weekly,Monthly,Financial
```

This code runs fine from the auto macro generated
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblWeekly").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
Array("Financial", "Weekly", "Monthly"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

I tried to JOIN the cell values and pass that into Criteria1 and it didn't work.

I now have this approach that is crazy clunky.

```
Sub Test_filter()
Dim ar As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String: str = vbNullString


ar = Split(shWeekly.Range("C5").Value, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
    str = str + """" & ar(i) & """, "
Next
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)

Debug.Print str


With shWeekly.ListObjects("tblWeekly").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array(str), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
End Sub
```

The TEXTFILTER shows this after it runs:   ="Weekly", "Monthly", "Financial", which is incorrect obviously.
How do I engage the selection of values vs TEXTFILTER?

Any ideas on how the ARRAY in correctly?

Thanks

Comment: `Criteria1:=Array(Split(shWeekly.Range("C5").Value, ","))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs only a small correction: `ar` is already the array you have to supply as `Criteria1`, you don't need to convert it to an array. If you do, it will be an array of arrays, and you don't want that.

```
Sub Test_filter()
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str As String: str = vbNullString
    
    
    ar = Split(shWeekly.Range("C5").Value, ",")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
        str = str + """" & ar(i) & """, "
    Next
    str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
    
    Debug.Print str
    
    
    With shWeekly.ListObjects("tblWeekly").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ar, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that `Criteria1:=Array(str),` was replaced with `Criteria1:=ar`.